# How do I split text (from Sheets) in Google Apps Script (in Slides)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-slides-api, google-slides

I am accessing data from Google Sheets and putting it onto Google Slides. The data I'm using has dates in the format "Thu Jan 30 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2020". I want to split it such that I only have "Thu Jan 30".

My code so far is:

```
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var date = data[i][0];
    var splitDate = date.split("00:00");
    Logger.log(splitDate[0]);
    Logger.log(data[i][1]);
  }
```

However, I get an error that says "TypeError: date.split is not a function". Is there another function I can use to split the date?

Comment: Using `getDisplayValues()` instead of `getValues()` might be the direct solution. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues()) But I'm not sure about the actual values of your Spreadsheet. So if this didn't resolve your issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Hi @Kirkland! Could you please share a copy of your spreadsheet to further help you with the issue? Please, remember to delete every private identifiable information.

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks @Tanaike !

Comment: Hi @Tanaike , could you please formalise your comment into an answer so that the original poster can accept it and it is easier to be seen by any member of the community?

Comment: @Mateo Randwolf Thank you for your comment. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, when `getValues()` is used, `Thu Jan 30 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2020` is retrieved. And you want to retrieve `Thu Jan 30`.

When `Thu Jan 30` is putting to the cell in the Spreadsheet, I think that `getDisplayValues()` might be suitable instead of `getValues()`.

#### Reference:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues())